# calculate mean of time string

Tags: matlab, time, average, mean

I have a time vector containing time expressed in `'dd/mm/yyy HH:MM:ss'`

```
time = {    '09/01/2012 23:57:00';
'11/01/2012 01:36:00';
'12/01/2012 00:48:00';
'13/01/2012 00:35:00';}
```

representing the time at which I go to bed.

I would like compute the mean of the elements in the time vector to know what time I go to bed in average.

If I run

```
datestr(mean(datenum(time,'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:ss')),'HH:MM:ss')
```

I get

```
ans =

12:44:00
```

that is wrong (for my goal, not matematically) since Matlab makes some mess between the first and second day...indeed they are not consecutive as the others..

How to fix this?

Comment: Isn't that correct? 1:00:00 + 22:00:00 = 23:00:00 and divide that by 2 you get 11:30:00.

Comment: Also I think your vector `time` and the vector name `test` used in `datestr` do not match

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. the mean between 01:00 AM and 22:00PM should be 23:30PM ...isn't it?

Comment: It is 24hr time so you can just treat them as straight numbers, there really is no distinction of AM/PM

Comment: Assuming that I go to bed the first day at 01:00 and the second day at 22:00 I would like to know the average time at which I go to bed...that is 23:30PM not 11:30AM...I meant this..

Comment: In the case of two different times, the average will assume they're both on the same day. The correct answer is 11.30; getting 23.30 requires stepping from one day to the next. You need to play a bit more if you want to assume the closes possible time lapse between the two times...

Comment: If you want to get this kind of mean, what you ask is to get 25:00 rather than 01:00. You ask day-by-day step

Comment: I would like to know if matlab has a built in function to handle this kind of problem (mean in a circle?)

Comment: You could force your AM times into theoretical PM times by adding 24 if to the hours if less than 12, but I am not sure if Matlab will know what to do with those in `datenum`. I don't have Matlab accessible so I can't try.

Comment: Hint: 24-hour time is non-Euclidean. Read up on circular statistics, e.g., [circular mean](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_mean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you haven't told Matlab that it is 01:00 the next day, you can't expect it to just assume that. In fact you are actually using date strings and not time strings. Matlab, for whatever reason, has decided that your dates are on the 1st of Jan 2015. To see this try:

```
time = {'01:00:00';
        '22:00:00'};
datestr(datenum(times));
```

I don't know why it picked the 1st of Jan 2015, but it does make sense that it consistently picked the same date for both times instead of somehow reading your mind and choosing the 01:00 to be the next day.

If you want to get it right then you need to include date information as well. Picking any arbitrary date as a base:

```
time = {'02-Jan-2015 01:00:00';
        '01-Jan-2015 22:00:00'}
```

Now your code should give you the time you wanted:

```
datestr(mean(datenum(time)),'HH:MM:ss')
```

Note if you wanted to automate this, you could say assume that any times before say 04:00 are the next day and then just add one day to those elements (after `datenum` of course)

---

Based on your edit:

```
time = {'09/01/2012 23:57:00';
        '11/01/2012 01:36:00';
        '12/01/2012 00:48:00';
        '13/01/2012 00:35:00';}  

hours = str2num(datestr(time, 'HH')); %// Extract just the hour from the datetime
t = datenum(datestr(time, 'HH:MM:ss')); %// Extract just the time (i.e. make everything on the same day
t = t+(hours<5); %// Add one day to everything after midnight. 5 is an assumption, you can tweak this cut-off time. 
datestr(mean(t),'HH:MM:ss')

ans =

00:44:00
```

By the way, you might want to check out the new [`datetime`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) data type. I haven't used it myself yet but just as an example, getting the hour of the time out would be a lot simpler (well, less hacky) and I'm sure there are plenty of other benefits too. Here is my attempt:

```
dates = datetime(time); %// using your time cell array of strings still
%// Now we must make them all the same arbitrary day:
dates.Day = 1;
dates.Year = 2015; %// or 0 or datetime('today').Year
dates.Month = 1;
%// Now we add days to those after midnight the same as before
dates.Day = dates.Day + (dates.Hour < 5);
mean(dates)  %// Or datestr(mean(dates),'HH:MM:ss')
```

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks a lot for your answer...I updated my question...I do have date information, but as you can see from my edited question it doesn't help..

Comment: @gabboshow you need to choose a base date, everything before midnight gets that one same date, everything after gets the date of the next day.

Comment: thanks again. the cut off time 5 means that if the time is less than 5AM you add 1 day...isn't it?

Comment: @gabboshow correct, so you must just choose the appropriate cutoff time for your use case